# How can I create this simple alert in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I am creating a simple website using HTML and JavaScript in dreamweaver. On my home page, I want to show an alert (whenever my home page loads), which says that "Hello, you are visitor no. 12. Welcome to my site!". I want this visitor number to change on every page load of home.html.

I basically want the visitor no. to be stored in a cookie and increase the no. by 1 in the cookie every time the page refreshes.

How can I create such an alert? Please help. Thanks.

Also, I want to know if I add this functionality, would it be an example of dynamic content on a web page or do you HAVE to create database connections and all in order to create dynamic content. Wouldn't this idea of creating cookie also an example of dynamic content?

Edit-1

I want that only. How many times page was visited. I am a beginner and want it all simple. I just want to know how I can store the no. of visits in a cookie and then retrieve that value from that cookie and show it in an alert on page load. Thanks.

Comment: A cookie wouldn't solve your problem and generate a count of users to your site. It would only tell the visitor how many times they have visited your site.

Comment: I want that only. How many times page was visited. I am a beginner and want it all simple. I just want to know how I can store the no. of visits in a cookie and then retrieve that value from that cookie and show it in an alert on page load. Thanks.

Comment: The cookie only saves information on the client side and will not keep a running total of total visitors to your site. For that yes, you would need a storage mechanism, like a database, on your server to store that information.

Comment: You want to know how many times visitor X has accessed your page?

Comment: You have to understand the difference between the total number of visits by anyone and the total number of visits for a single visitor. Your question sounds like you want the former ("You are visitor no. 26259") but with cookies you can only get the latter ("You have visited this site 2 times").

Comment: So does that mean if I implement this cookie, it is not dynamic content?

Comment: Dynamic content doesn't have much to do with that. Content is dynamic if it's generated on visit or it changes due to user action; displaying a visit count would be "dynamic" either way.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it really simple for you (without using the database) you can store the number in a .txt file in the server, and use a simple scripting language like PHP to send it in a hidden field to the client. Every time the PHP page runs, it will have to get the current number and increment it. Something like this:

```
$myFile = "counter.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$count = fgets($fh);
$count++;
fclose($fh);

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $count); // write the incremented counter
fclose($fh);

echo "<input type='hidden' id='counter' value='$count'>";
```

Then, you would have to get this counter value from the javascript (client side) and alert to the user.

```
var visitCount = document.getElementById('counter');
alert("Hello, you are visitor no. "+visitCount+". Welcome to my site!");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the number of visitors, you'll need to use a backend scripting framework (PHP, Ruby, Rails, Python, etc) to store the number of visits your page has received in a database.  The javascript of displaying the actual number is simple, with `alert('message');`

If you just want the number of times that specific user has visited, based on their local information, here's a simple solution:

```
if (localStorage.numVisits)
    numVisits = localStorage.numVisits;
else
    numVisits = 0;

alert("Welcome, you have visited " + numVisits + " times before.");    

localStorage.numVisits++;
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you fixed it before seeing my comment so I deleted it.

Comment: I am confused. is it dynamic content or not? :/

Comment: @Serenity what do you mean by dnyamic?  This will increase each time a single user visits your page, for that user only.  For example, if I visit your page 12 times, it will tell me I have visited 12 times.  Afterwards, someone else can visit, and it will tell them it is their first visit.

Comment: Why are you so fixated on it being dynamic? Is this homework?

Comment: Does "backend scripting" imply "you need a server" (relative to just having a webpage and some javascript), or are there other ways to implement those backend scripts?

Comment: @Keikoku you need a server to 'serve' a webpage regardless.  By backend scripting I just mean some language you use to generate the HTML/CSS/Javascript that gets served to the clients upon request.

Comment: lol it was worded badly. For example I use free web-hosting services to get my webpage out there (just small things, mostly one-time things), and it doesn't give me any way to host my own server scripts.

Comment: @Keikoku Most free web hosting services allow PHP/mySQL at a bare minimum.

Comment: I think it's time for the usual: Please try to read some tutorials before putting up a webpage where you don't even know what it does.

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to create the table and every time when session is start u need to increase +1 in there table and alert the visitor no.

table like

```
   id : no
   -------
   1  : 3
   2  : 5
```

and massage like

```
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"Hello, you are visitor no. {$row["no"]}. Welcome to my site!\");
        </script>
    ";
```

Answer (score 2):

A Cookie is always Client-sided! You can't do it that way. The easiest way to accomplish what you are looking for is to write a simple php counter which reads a number from a file - adds one and writes it back as soon as your page is viewed.

Check google for examples on "counters".

There actually is no way to count clientsided ALL the visitors you have or had - the client can't know that your server was visited x times ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot keep a global page view count in a cookie.  A cookie is stored in one user's browser and is local only to that browser.  All a cookie could show would the page views that occurred in that one single browser.

Page view counts across all viewers must be done at the server level and then the information put into the page when the page is requested.  There are some free ways to put page view counts into the page using the free service level of services like [StatCounter](http://statcounter.com/).

Or, you'd have to implement a counter in your own server that was serving the page (with the count probably stored in a persistent database) and then insert the current count into the page each time it is requested.  For just page count information, it's probably easiest to just go with a service like Statcounter.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not persistent across different visitors. To give every visitor a visitor number, you need something stored on a server. If you cannot access server-side functions, use a visitor counter - https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=visitor+counter